# PHP Regular Expression difference

Tags: php, expression

Can someone explain the difference between these two lines of code?

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $Phone);

preg_replace('/[^0-9\/+]/', '', $Phone);
```

Ive been hunting online and cant seem to find anything explaining the extra "/+"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following matches anything that's not a digit.

```
/[^0-9]/
```

The following matches anything that's not a digit, `/`, or `+`:

```
/[^0-9/+]/
```